# how to get my fender mustang working on ubuntu studio?

Tags: drivers, sound, usb, audio-jack

I’m new to Linux and I use Ubuntu Studio and being a adept Windows user my troubleshooting capabilities are bound to GUI and not emulator.

Coming to the problem, I would like to use my Fender Mustang guitar amplifier on Ubuntu studio..
so,

my Mustang amplifier is not detected by Ubuntu through USB port,

```
antony@antony-OptiPlex-9020:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:4e22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1130:1620 Tenx Technology, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1058:10b8 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 054c:05b7 Sony Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mustang-plug/

tried this doesn’t work

made rule exception and put it in proper folder

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/50-mustang.rules
```

and pasted this as suggested in plug website

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8",
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0004", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8",
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0005", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1ed8",
ATTRS{idProduct}=="0006", GROUP="plugdev"
```

then I try to compile it after getting qt4 and `libusb-dev` using

```
antony@antony-OptiPlex-9020:~$ cd plug-1.1-x86-64
antony@antony-OptiPlex-9020:~/plug-1.1-x86-64$ qmake plug
WARNING: /home/antony/plug-1.1-x86-64/plug:2: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated.
WARNING: /home/antony/plug-1.1-x86-64/plug:5: Unmatched quotes are deprecated.
Braces mismatch /home/antony/plug-1.1-x86-64/plug:7
Error processing project file: plug
```

and here is the list of my playback devices

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3220 Analog [ALC3220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI_1 [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: AUDIO [USB  AUDIO], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

So there I get a warning and error which I don’t have a clue what it is.

Checked it out in QjackCTL didn’t find my device anywhere..

Using my Fender Mustang presently with fuse in Windows, I would enjoy using with Linux..

Comment: If a USB device isn't listed by `lsusb`, unfortunately no driver or (user space) software can help you. Are you sure that you connected the USB device to a working USB host port? According to http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/plug-and-fender-mustang the Linux kernel supports the Fender Mustang since at least 5 years, so the problem is likely not a missing device driver.

Comment: It may be helpful to run `sudo dmesg` just after plugging in the USB device and see, if any related messages turn up. Post the relevant output here if any.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thank you for your useful comment,yes the fender mustang is working using plug ([link]https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mustang-plug/)

Comment: Are you saying, that you got it to work? In that case, please explain how in an answer and accept it.

Comment: There is a package `mustang-plug` in ubuntu repo, see also this for further configuration step http://lifeofageekadmin.com/install-plug-linux-software-fender-mustang-fedora24/

Answer (score -1):

You should use a AV specialized distro as the system is optimized very different from a desktop.

See http://libremusicproduction.com/articles/advantages-choosing-audio-orientated-linux-distribution for details

Try Ubuntu studio or KXStudio or Fedora Jam (KXStudio is my personal favorite)

http://ubuntustudio.org/

http://kxstudio.sourceforge.net/

http://spins.fedoraproject.org/jam-kde/

Support on IRC at #linuxmusicians

Support is limited on "standard desktop" versions due to the various customizations to AV oriented spins.

Comment: i added KXstudio software repositories to my current installation of Ubuntu studio, thanks again for mentioning it

Comment: Does Cadence recognize your usb device (Cadence configures Jack)? http://kxstudio.sourceforge.net/Applications:Cadence

Comment: I assume "card 3: AUDIO [USB  AUDIO], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]" is your device , but I can not tell if your problem is with Jack or with the application you are wanting to use .... Personally I find nothing beats a hardware mixer ;)

Comment: nope card 3 is my usb speakers..cadence is not available for ubuntu studio

Comment: You can manually install Cadence. It is a binary - apt://cadence or http://sourceforge.net/projects/kxstudio/files/Releases/cadence/Cadence-0.8.1-linux32.tar.xz/download or http://sourceforge.net/projects/kxstudio/files/Releases/cadence/Cadence-0.8.1-linux64.tar.xz/download

Comment: -1 None of these help, if the USB stack doesn't even see the device.

Comment: ok so how do i make it available in USB stack?

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment